# Find last line of a file for matching string?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want a loop that runs infinitely over a file but always checks the last line to see if it contains the matching string if it does then echo that line and keep the loop running. What I have right now doesn't work I get an error for grep

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Script is starting......."
FILE="/Users/shubhamsinha/Desktop/new_test.log"
# (tail -n1) < FILE
STRING="MYNAME"
while : ;do
    Last = tail -F "$FILE"
    grep -q "$STRING" "$Last" && echo "FOUND" && break
    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: Here is my code for it: 

    #! /bin/bash

    echo "Script is starting......."
    FILE="/Users/shubhamsinha/Desktop/new_test.log"
    # (tail -n1) < FILE
    STRING="MYNAME"
    while : ;do
     Last = tail -F "$FILE"
        grep -q "$STRING" "$Last" && echo "FOUND" && break
        sleep 5
    done

Comment: What about something like `tail -f "$FILE" | grep "$STRING"`?

Comment: what do I delete and where do I insert that line in the code?

Comment: Replace the entire while-loop with that line.

Comment: It just echoes "Script is starting......." and nothing happens

Comment: And then what happens when you add a line containing that string to the file ?

Comment: Don't use ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES. One day you'll use PATH=something and your script breaks.

Comment: so I add the following to my new_test.log file:
    dsfds
    MYNAME
    dsfsd
    sdfsdfsdf
    sdfsdfsdf

    sdfsdf

   sdfsdfsdf
   MYNAME
   sdsfsdf
   sdfsdf
   sdfsdfdsf

And in the terminal where the script is running this is what I see:
   MYNAME
   MYNAMEdsfds
    MYNAME
MYNAME
MYNAME
MYNAME

Comment: I basically want a running script that constantly only checks the last line and if it matches the string then it echoes that line and continues. So I am thinking something along the lines of a conditional expression that checks that

Comment: @user1585869 why aren't you just filtering the process which generates the log like `logging_proc | tee -a log | sed -ne'/MYNAME/c\' -eFOUND`? That would be way easier, and would avoid many buffer issues you might encounter otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

**Don't bother making a script.  This calls for a one-liner, not a script.**

Leverage existing tools to do what you need in preference to writing a new tool.

Just type this on the command line:

```
tail -f -n 1 /Users/shubhamsinha/Desktop/new_test.log | grep MYNAME
```

---

**Explanation:**

`tail -f` runs forever on the specified file and outputs every additional line that is added to the file.

`-n 1` means that when `tail` is starting it will only output the current last line of the file, rather than the last 10 lines of the file which is the default.

`|` is a pipe.  If you don't know about pipes, drop everything, don't try and write any more shell scripts, until you understand pipes.  (It won't take very long but is *crucial* to writing good scripts.)

`grep MYNAME` prints only the lines of its input that contain the pattern MYNAME.

Comment: You want to add `-m 1` to `grep` to cause it to exit on the first match.  Alternatively, `grep -q` will also have that behavior, but not print anything (if you really want to print something less informative than the actual match after it finishes instead).

Comment: Also, `tail -F` like in the OP's question has some advantages over `tail -f`.

Comment: True, if your `grep` and `tail` support those flags.  The above is POSIX compliant.  I'll leave it as-is but thanks for noting those options!

Comment: "tail -f runs forever on the specified file." Then when will "tail -f " stops if it runs forever? Thanks

Comment: @Edamame when it's killed.  If you're running it interactively, use Ctrl-C to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Script is starting......."
FILE="/Users/shubhamsinha/Desktop/new_test.log"

STRING="MYNAME"

while true; do
    tail bar | grep "MYNAME" && echo "FOUND" && break
    sleep 5
done
```

---

*Example*

- `FILE="/home/user1/tmp/bar"`
- Script name is `foo`

  ```
  % ./foo &                  
  [1] 12586
  Script is starting.......                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  % echo "MYNAME" > ~/tmp/bar
  % MYNAME
  FOUND

  [1]  + 12586 done       ./foo
  ```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using the `tail` command, use `awk` to get perfect output.

```
Last = tail -F "$FILE"  ===>  Last=$(awk '/./{line=$0} END{print line}' $FILE)
```

Comment: How does this replace `tail -f | grep` ?  Please explain

Comment: I got answer from - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638912/how-do-i-get-the-last-non-empty-line-of-a-file-using-tail-in-bash